# Lets Encrypt Certificate Renewal failing

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I followed the tutorial here for setting up a Let's Encrypt certificate originally and it has been working great: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

I'm now to the point where I'm trying to renew the certificate but it keeps failing with a 404. I have researched numerous places and even tried several things I have found in similar posts on Stack Overflow. I'm using Nginx as a proxy pass to an embedded Tomcat servlet running a Spring Boot application which uses spring security. The below config is my current configuration. The issue seems to be that the renewal process is not able to hit the generated file for the acme-challenge. Running the command "sudo letsencrypt renew" never actually created the directory "acme-challenge" under the directory ".well-known". I manually created the directory and added a file called "test" with the contents "success" inside that file. And I am able to retrieve this file and see the contents of it in my browser but the acme-challenge created by lets encrypt still fails.

If any of you can see something I'm not getting, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm not an expert on Let's Encrypt or Nginx by any means.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Default Config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                default_type "text/plain";
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-mysite.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
             allow all;
        }
}
```

mysite.com Config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    #include snippets/ssl-mysite.com.conf;
    #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/;

    proxy_cache one;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the acme directory have proper permissions for nginx to access it?

Comment: I have set the permissions on both the .well-know and acme-challenge directories to 755.

Comment: There are some useful checkpoint in the documentation: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/challenges.html